# MySQL Case when joining two tables

Tags: mysql, join, comparison, case

I have a question concerning mySQL :

I have two tables.

```
Table 1
```

[image: Table 1]

In the `table 2`, I have the same 5 idprojet, but with various datedebut and various datefin.

[image: Table 2]

I need to fin a way to know if the smaller "datedebut" for each project in `table2` is smaller than the datedebut from `table1`, and if the biggest "datefin" for each project in `table2` is bigger than the datefin from `table1`.

I wrote this request

```
SELECT table1.idprojet,
case when table1.datedebut < table2.tab2min then 'False'
else 'True' end as dateDebutComparison,
case when table2.dateFin > table1.dateFin then 'True'
else 'False' end as dateFinComparison
FROM table1, table2
JOIN (select table2.idProjet, MIN(dateDEBUT) tab2min, MAX(dateFIN) tab2max FROM table2 GROUP BY idProjet) table2
ON table2.idProjet = table1.idProjet
```

But it gives me the following mistake :

```
Error Code: 1052. Column 'table2.idProjet' in on clause is ambiguous
```

The outpout would be something like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `table2` does not need to appear in your main query.
The following query should be right. I changed the subquery alias to avoid confusion with the `table2` table name.

```sql
SELECT 
    table1.idprojet,
    CASE WHEN table1.datedebut < minMaxTable2.tab2min THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS dateDebutComparison,
    CASE WHEN minMaxTable2.tab2max > table1.dateFin THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS dateFinComparison
FROM table1
     JOIN (SELECT table2.idProjet, MIN(table2.dateDEBUT) tab2min, MAX(table2.dateFIN) tab2max 
           FROM table2
           GROUP BY table2.idProjet
     ) minMaxTable2
ON minMaxTable2.idProjet = table1.idProjet
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Exactly what I needed!